# Unable to remove horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to replace the horizontal scrollbar in this code to arrow buttons ( not entire page but the images scrolling).

I used this code

```
.scroll-images::-webkit-scrollbar{
            -webkit-appearance: none;
        }
```

But the scrollbar is not getting removed.
This is the entire code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Horizontal Scroll Bar</title>
    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            background-color: black;
        }
        body {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .main-scroll-div{
            width: 90%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
            border: 2px solid red;
        }

        .cover{
            position: relative;
            width: 90%;
            height: 50%;
        }

        .scroll-images{
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: left;
            align-items: center;
            overflow: auto;
            position: relative;
            scroll-behavior: smooth;
        }

       

        .child{
            min-width: 600px;
            height: 450px;
            margin: 1px 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 1px solid white;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .child-img{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;

        }

        .scroll-images::-webkit-scrollbar{
            -webkit-appearance: none;
        }

        .icon{
            color: green;
            background-color: black;
            font-size: 50px;
            outline: none;
            border: none;
            padding: opx 20px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-scroll-div">
        <div>
            <button class ="icon"> <i class="left"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class ="cover">
            <div class="scroll-images">
                <div class="child"><img class="child-img" src="imges/1.jpg" alt="image"></div>
                <div class="child"><img class="child-img" src="imges/2.jpg" alt="image"></div>
                <div class="child"><img class="child-img" src="imges/3.jpg" alt="image"></div>
                <div class="child"><img class="child-img" src="imges/4.jpg" alt="image"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class ="icon"> <i class="left"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried
`display : none` but it also didn't work.
also
`appearance : none`

Answer (score 0):

I dont no that much but try this

```
.scroll-images {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: Yes it works. But now my doubt is does it get cut off. I want to add a button to right for scroll.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

::-webkit-scrollbar is non-standard and you need to check for cross-browser before using it. Try this:

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
-ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
```

Comment: Oh ok. I was viewing in firefox. Will i be able to scroll using button if i use this?

Comment: Yes, try:    .scroll-images {
            scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */        
        }

Comment: K will try that.